# Переходы между формами без использования NavigationController

Tags: xcode, swift

В приложении две формы, переход с главной на вторую сделал без проблем без использования Navigate Controllera - поместил кнопку и создал Sigue типа Modal но обратно вернуться на главную форму этот метод не годится так как приложение представляет из себя плеер и при использовании модального отображения второй формы при возврате на главную плеер продолжает играть не обновляя контролы -ползунок , время кнопки play итд ... при использовании для перехода метода Sigue типа Push вылетает ошибка (скрин) ... вроде все сделал правильно создал класс для формы итд... Navigate Controller решает проблему но его использовать не хочется так как он нарушает созданные правила разметки(constraints) - подскажите какие у меня варианты??
[image: тынц]
<sub>(источник: [cs628230.vk.me](http://cs628230.vk.me/v628230810/fea6/Xmx6UCHbsT0.jpg))</sub>

Comment: И каким же образом UINavigateController нарушает constrains?

Comment: добавляет панель сверху... все слетает... панель удалить не могу, она не нужна...  я новичок если что... если что то упускаю поправьте

Comment: В UI Builder в Xcode, для каждого UIViewController можно убрать все панели, которые не нужны.

Comment: писал же панель не удаляется

Comment: Добавьте что бы скрыть бар
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

Comment: @Zarochintsev Спасибо! Это реально решение!

Answer (score 1):

Решение от @Zarochintsev

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Answer (score -2):

Нашел решение на англоязычном форуме. Можно закрывать модальную форму так:

```
@IBAction func backToMain(sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}
```